# Get system specific line break in .net

Tags: .net, cross-platform, eol

Is there a way to get the current systems line break character(s) in the .net framework?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[`Environment.NewLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline.aspx) will give you the newline string defined for the current platform and implementation of the .NET Framework.

Answer (score 4):

```
System.Environment.NewLine
```

Answer (score 3):

Environment.NewLine [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline.aspx)